# Undefined symbol error, Unity Project with Firebase Analytics when building Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I am facing an Undefined symbol error in XCode project and cannot solve it.

My latest build app is already used with ARCore, Firebase, and Facebook SDK. And it builds normally on Android and IOS.
In this update, I need to add some custom tracking events of Firebase Analytics. After my update, it works on Android but fails in XCode.

Here is the code that was added to the project:
[New code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUz4r.png)

The different update only:
`FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent( FirebaseAnalytics.EventScreenView, new Parameter(FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterScreenName, "000_IntroScene"));`

I have tried to remove this code and build it again, it works very well.

Here is my environment information:

Build Environment: MacOS 12.4
Unity Version: 2021.3.1f1
XCode Version: 13.4.1 (13F100)
Firebase Version: 9.1.0

Pod List:
[Pod List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NOuG.png)

Error Message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEzoQ.png)

Sorry for I am new on StackOverflow and cannot embed the picture in the post. Does anyone have any idea to solve this issue? Thank you.

I tried these methods:

- Update Firebase from 9.1.0 to 9.6.0
- Replace the files on "./Assets/Firebase/Editor", follow this link https://github.com/techyworm10/firebase-unity-sdk-editor-python-fix

Answer (score 0):

please try the following (if you have not already):

Make sure the game [compiles and runs in the editor](https://github.com/firebase/level-up-with-firebase/blob/main/build-and-debug-guide.md#play-in-editor-compile-time-issues-) (while targeting ibefore exporting to Xcode.

- If it cannot compile, have you added the necessary SDKs?
- If it does not run have you included the necessary config files?

If it is failing to build for a target platform, make sure you have included the external dependency manager (EDM4U).

If EDM4U has been included, follow this [resolver debug guide](https://github.com/firebase/level-up-with-firebase/blob/main/build-and-debug-guide.md#resolver-and-target-device-build-errors) while trying to solve the issues.

Try to address as many of both warnings and errors during iOS resolution as possible.

Please tell me how the above works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop application does not seem to support analytics yet
[firebase for desktop](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#analytics-enabled)
I also want to know when the development plan will support

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34159939)